# Ranking in complete binary trees

Tags: algorithm-analysis, trees, binary-trees

I have a binary tree, the node has two subtrees, every node except the the leaves, has 2 children and all the leaves are at the same level.

I want to know the worst and best case complexities when I applied centralized ranking to **this** type of tree. (defined above)

For the worst case, O(n^2) happens when the tree is chain. But what about this kind of tree? What is the best and worst case complexities of this kind of tree?

Comment: Looks like this is cross posted from stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007592/ranking-in-the-binary-trees

Comment: What is centralized ranking?

Comment: Your constraints force the tree to be binary complete, i.e. the only paramater is its depth. You have exactly one tree of each height, and a chain is not possible.

Comment: Please don't crosspost; respect the time answerers take and only post to other sites if you don't get good answers after a couple of days (or, better, request migration).